# character recognition from machine part with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a project about recognizing characters from machine part with opencv python with this image:

[image]

This image is captured by logitech c615 camera .i want to detect perfect text on that machine part.

I tried with easyocr and the result is :

```
final ['(ER--', '827818,303"', '821698,', 'I(dia']
```

And now I really don't know what to do. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import easyocr

IMAGE_FILE_LOCATION = r'D:\camera_mv_image\IMAGES\date (1).jpeg'
input_img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_FILE_LOCATION)

bfilter = cv2.bilateralFilter(input_img, 15, 30, 30)
bfilter = cv2.cvtColor(bfilter, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(bfilter, -1, sharpen_kernel)

cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext(sharpen,detail=0)
print("final",result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate the region of interest (the text) first and call `readtext()` on each individual line. If that's insufficient, locate each individual character within each line and call `readtext()` on each individual character like I demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68521734/14432704